# Instance is executed even though not invoked

Tags: javascript

I imported an awesome markdown editor `simplemde`

```
<script src='{% static "simplemde/debug/simplemde.js" %}'></script>
<script>

var simplemde = new SimpleMDE({
        element: document.getElementById("content"),
        autoDownloadFontAwesome: false,
        status: false,
});
</script>
```

It works well when I refresh the page,

[image]

However, I am confused here,

I simply declare an variable `var simplemde` to create an instance, but did not invoke it.

If not invoked,how could it execute to parse the page?

Comment: `new SimpleMDE()` does

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The script was not executed here:

```
var simplemde
```

The script was executed here:

```
new SimpleMDE({
    element: document.getElementById("content"),
    autoDownloadFontAwesome: false,
    status: false,
});
```

Because in essense, `SimpleMDE` is a function, and every function gets executed once there is a parenthesis behind it, for instance, `SimpleMDE()`.

So when you do (note the parenthesis after `SimpleMDE`):

```
var simplemde = new SimpleMDE({
    element: document.getElementById("content"),
    autoDownloadFontAwesome: false,
    status: false,
});
```

What you actually doing here is that you first execute the block `new SimpleMDE(...)`, then pass the executed value into `var simplemde`.

If you don't want it to be executed, you can do:

```
var simplemde = SimpleMDE;
```

Then later on, when you want to execute it, you can do:

```
new simplemde({...});
```

But it will be very confusing and not a good way to do it. So try not to do it that way.

Comment: ty  for the perfect tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

`SimpleMDE` can be either a class with a `constructor` or `SimpleMDE` is simply a function. When we execute it with a `new` keyword, if `SimpleMDE` is a class, `constructor` will be executed immediately, while if `SimpleMDE` is a function, using a `new` keyword will turns it into a `constructor` function, and creates an instance out of it.

For more information you can have a look at [new operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new)

Answer (score 1):

The `SimpleMDE` function is a constructer. When you make an object like that instance `simplemde` it invokes all of the code within that function. Something like:

`function SimpleMDE (argument) {
      this.variable = argument:
      parsePage();
}`

Constructed of objects run all the code within them just like any other function. Every time you reload the page the constructer is called as is the code inside it.

I hope this answers the question and I’m sorry if I misunderstood you.